# Python code to add GeoIP data to a Suricata eve.json log

Tags: python, json

I wrote this script as part of a Suricata course where I had to annotate destination IP addresses with GeoIP data in an EVE JSON log file.

I would like your input on my code style and smell, especially the `gen_geoip()` function - it takes an IP address and return a "geoip" JSON object. It is very compact and it has a Lisp look for me (I never wrote Lisp). I feel like I am not doing it in the right style but I can't find a better way to do it. So what do you think ?

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from json import loads as json_loads
from json import dump  as json_dump
import ipaddress
import sys
import maxminddb
# You may need to change the path just below
geoip = maxminddb.open_database('/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb')
home_net = {ipaddress.ip_network('172.16.0.0/12')} # <- Suricata HOME_NET

def gen_geoip(ip):
    ip_addr = ipaddress.ip_address(ip)
    if any(map(lambda net: ip_addr in net,home_net)):
        # This IP is within our home network
        return {'country': 'local'}
    else:
        return dict(map(lambda keyval: (keyval[0], keyval[1]['names']['en']), (geoip.get(ip) or {}).items()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for line in sys.stdin:
        json = json_loads(line)
        if 'dest_ip' in json:
            json['geoip'] = gen_geoip(json['dest_ip'])
        json_dump(json,sys.stdout)
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Example stripped output with beautified JSON:

```json
{
  "event_type": "dns",
  "src_ip": "172.16.0.153",
  "src_port": 52054,
  "dest_ip": "172.16.0.12",
  "dest_port": 53,
  "geoip": {
    "country": "local"
  }
}
{
  "event_type": "http",
  "src_ip": "172.16.0.153",
  "src_port": 57580,
  "dest_ip": "67.205.184.237",
  "dest_port": 80,
  "geoip": {
    "continent": "North America",
    "country": "United States",
    "registered_country": "United States"
  }
}
```